# How to get data from controller to view

Tags: codeigniter

I have function in controller

```
function test() {
        $data['lang'] = read_file(APPPATH . "language/bahasa/english.php");
        $this->load->view('test', $data);
    }
```

english.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$lang['content.home'] = 'Home';
$lang['content.about_us'] = 'About Us';
$lang['content.team'] = 'Team';
$lang['content.contact'] = 'Contact us';
```

How to get data $lang['content.home'] = 'home' in view

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing your own method for retrieving language files? There is a [language class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html) which would handle this for you.

Using `$this->load->view('test', $data)` is the right way to get the properties of `$data` into your view. That said, if your `read_file()` usage is working, your data in the view would be in `$lang['content.home']`, etc.

Comment: i think to adding language via admin panel, so we can generate new language using admin panel not from script. any idea?

Comment: That is a whole different question which you'd be better off asking separately. In that instance I'd imagine you would need to extend or build your own language class that would pull language from your database.